# Getting argument in Vimperator user command

Tags: vimperator

I want to search words in an online dictionary site Weblio, using Vimperator command-line.

Here is how to call: `http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/[someword]`

And I made following an incomplete code in `~/.vimperator.rc`:

```
command weblio :o 
  javascript:javascript:window.location='http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/word';
```

I'm in trouble over how to get argument from Vimperator command-line.

I think that would be following command:

```
:weblio [someword]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
command! -nargs=1 weblio open http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/<args>
```

Documentation is available at `:help command`.